# Error while using FullSimplify

Tags: performance-tuning, simplifying-expressions, mathematical-optimization

I am trying to simplify a particular expression using `Collect`, `Series`, and `FullSimplify`:

```
Collect[Normal[Series[(2^(1 - 2 eps) E^((eps EulerGamma (-1 + n))/(1 + n))
 Gamma[1/2 - eps] Gamma[-eps] Gamma[-((2 eps)/(1 + n))])/((1 + n) 
 Sqrt[\[Pi]] Gamma[1 - eps] Gamma[-2 eps]), {eps, 0, 4}]], eps, FullSimplify]
```

This results in incomplete expression

[image]

Using `Simplify` instead of `FullSimplify` works well and does not lead to this problem.

**Is it a bug or is there a way around the problem (keeping FullSimplify)?**

*"13.3.1 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)"*

Comment: It certainly looks like a bug worth reporting to the [WRI](https://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/?topic=feedback). As a workaround, using [`FunctionExpand`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FunctionExpand.html) as a preprocessing step seems to work: `Collect[FunctionExpand@Normal@Series[(2^(1 - 2 eps) E^((eps EulerGamma (-1 + n))/(1 + n)) Gamma[1/2 - eps] Gamma[-eps] Gamma[-((2 eps)/(1 + n))])/((1 + n) Sqrt[π] Gamma[1 - eps] Gamma[-2 eps]), {eps, 0, 4}], eps, FullSimplify]`, and it gives quite a nice concise result.

Comment: @Domen          This is quite good! And fast too! This could be an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It certainly looks like a bug worth reporting to the [WRI](https://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/?topic=feedback).

As a workaround, using [`FunctionExpand`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FunctionExpand.html) as a preprocessing step seems to work, and it gives quite a nice concise result:

```
series = 
  Normal@Series[(2^(1 - 2 eps) E^((eps EulerGamma (-1 + n))/(1 + n)) Gamma[
       1/2 - eps] Gamma[-eps] Gamma[-((2 eps)/(1 + n))])/((1 + 
        n) Sqrt[\[Pi]] Gamma[1 - eps] Gamma[-2 eps]), {eps, 0, 4}];

res = Collect[FunctionExpand@series, eps, FullSimplify]
```

[image]

Numerically, it looks like nothing went wrong during `FunctionExpand` and `FullSimplify`:

```
And @@ Table[series == res /. {eps -> RandomReal[], n -> RandomInteger[]}, 500]
(* True *)
```